# im using swift on xcode with Parse and keep getting the same error on a code that just worked for me earlier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I keep receiving the following error:

[image: error]

in the logs i get

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

the reason im having trouble with this is because i ran this code earlier and it worked fine can somebody please help and tell me where im going wrong in the code?
here is the full code

```
 import UIKit
import Parse


class HomePage: UITableViewController {

var images = [UIImage]()
var titles = [String]()
var imageFile = [PFFile]()
var voteCounter = [Int]()





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println(PFUser.currentUser())

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")

    var voteCount = PFObject(className: "Post")
    voteCount["voteCounter"] = voteCounter
    voteCount.saveInBackground()



    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil  {

            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

            for object in objects! {

                self.titles.append(object["Title"] as! String)

                self.imageFile.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println(error)
        }
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return titles.count


}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 500

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! cell

    myCell.rank.text = "21"
    myCell.votes.text = "\(voteCounter)"
    myCell.postDescription.text = titles[indexPath.row]

    imageFile[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage

        }
    }



    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


    var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    myCell.postedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    myCell.postedImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    return myCell

}


func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        var voteCounter = 0
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                voteCounter += 1
                println("Swiped right")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                voteCounter -= 1
                println("Swiped Left")
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

}
```

also any further advice or comments would be appreciated im fairly new to programming

Comment: Looks like `object["Title"]` is nil, or isn't a String. Check with a breakpoint, or breakdown the code to inspect elements (make `object["Title"] as! String` a variable that you can inspect before appending it to the array).

Comment: i thought so too but even if i erase that then it simply goes down and makes the imageFile line right under in to an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil  {

        println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

        for object in objects! {
            if let dict = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
               if let title = object["Title"] as? String {
                  self.titles.append(title)
               }
               if let imgFile = object["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                  self.imageFile.append(imgFile)
               }
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason when i run that code then nothing on the tableview comes up i just get an empty table

Comment: Check for objects count. What this line is printing         println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
?

Comment: it says successfully retrieved 4 scores. but theres nothing on the simulators table

Comment: Then your objects is not an Array of Dictionary. What this objects Array will give you?

Comment: no its just an array should i make it into an array of dictionary? and if so how could i do that?

Comment: @DanielWolfgangTrebek What you are expecting that array to hold? if dictionary, make it as dictionary, if some model class, convert it to array of that model class.

Comment: i was hoping to store the pictures that are uploaded on to there. will a dictionary be better for that?

Comment: Just add this line to print details of objects. println(objects!)

Comment: i did that but how can i make the the images and other objects appear on my table?

Comment: @DanielWolfgangTrebek after println(objects!), you will get to know, what the Array holds, based on that you need to change this line. if let dict = object as? [String: AnyObject] {} You need to check and change.

Comment: thsi is what i get Successfully retrieved 4 scores.
[<Post: 0x7bc83e40, objectId: vfbJECMwub, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7bc95b30>";
    Title = "balogna 2012";
    imageFile = "<PFFile: 0x7ae75f70>";
    userId = OhbjjR92q6;
    username = "<PFUser: 0x7ae7c290, objectId: OhbjjR92q6>";
}

Comment: i got it i deleted the if let dict = object as? [String: AnyObject] {} and now its working for me thank you for your help i appreciate it